# MATE Command Applet - '#' being shown instead of output

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm using the Command Applet 1.16.0 in MATE to run a bash command -

```
upower -d | grep -m1 "percentage" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Instead of showing the output I see in the terminal (battery percentage), it just shows a #

Can I not pipe commands in this applet, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hello! did you ever figure this out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

`bash -c "upower -d | grep -m1 "percentage" | awk '{print $2}'"`.

[Source](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-applets/issues/309#issuecomment-366177173)